# Emacs not inheriting transparency from terminal

Tags: term

When I run Emacs in a terminal window, via emacs - nw or emacsclient, Emacs loads in the terminal but without transparency.   (My terminal windows are set around 50 percent transparency.)   What could be the problem?  I'm running xfce4.  Thanks

Comment: Are you using a custom theme for your Emacs? Can you run `emacs -Q` in your terminal and tell us if the problem persist?

Comment: Thanks, I was using a theme.  Disabling it results in the expected transparency behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the problem?

There is some custom Emacs themes that, when used, can result to this kind of problem. Try with another theme, or tweak the used theme, until the expected transparency is back.